# Create an Ionic Plugin not with Native Java code

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, plugins

Hi I've developed one plugin for Emojis in Ionic that I want should be available to everyone.
But After searching on internet, the creation of Ionic plugin I got posts like making native code of Java to Cordova and Ionic capable.

I have pure JS code in my Ionic project. I tried to find but didn't get any success.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks